# Adding pictures to Print Composer from paths in table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

For each feature I want a picture related to that feature. So its obvious to have written a path in the tables attribute. Then I´ll label that attribute somehow by brackets like [%path%]. But it´s not that simple and need some guidance how to write it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you print using the Atlas feature from the Print Composer you can databind a column with the entire file path to a composer image.

[image]

Comment: Yup, I´ve found out too :-)

Comment: Would you mind to show the variable introduced to databind the path with the entire file path? I'm not available to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another convenient way to get the path of your pictures if they are located in your project directory is to use the **project_folder** variable from Field calculator:

[image]

This is especially useful in the print composer or Atlas when using a **relative save path** for your project since if you move the whole project folder, the picture path will be updated in the image source.

An example of the syntax would be: 
**@project_folder ||'/field_pictures/'||"picture_id"**

This is will retrieve the project folder path, then goes to the picture folder path and finally retrieves the picture_id from your attribute table.

And finally if you have some features which don't have a picture linked to it, you can avoid the ugly big red cross filling the blank image space by using a condition such as:
**CASE WHEN "picture_id" is not null THEN @project_folder ||'/field_pictures/'||"picture_id" ELSE ' ' END**